# Angular Is it possible to deselect radio button after a save?

Tags: angular, list

I have a form in angular with a list of radio button + label associated, and I would like to know is ot was possible to déselect button choosed by the user after a click on Cancel button ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using a form control to control the radio buttons or ngModel? Can you provide a code snippet with how your code looks in order to give you a specific answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you use reactive form you can do this:

```
resetRadio(){
   this.yourFormGroup.get("yourControl").reset();
}
```

where yourControl is FormControl of radio and yourFormGroup is its FormGroup:

Then you can call this function on click event of the button:

```
<button (click) =" resetRadio()">Reset Radio </button>
```